# What to do with a frozen web page in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, freeze, clipboard, webpage

I've typed a bunch of text into a web page in Google Chrome.  Suddenly, the page freezes.  How  can I copy the text to somewhere else, since I can't select it?  The page also stores the text in a variable if that helps anything.  I am running Linux Mint and the text is not all visible.

Comment: Since you've not mentioned your operating system it's a bit difficult to answer.  You might be able to capture the screen (in Windows) by hitting Alt-PrtScrn and then pasting the resulting graphic into Paint or Word.  In Ubuntu, the same key combo will allow you to save the graphic.  In the long run, you'll need to retype the text but at least you'll have a screen capture to work from.

Comment: Rather than trying to fix the symptoms, is there nothing you can do to cure the problem in the first place? Is it only Chrome that freezes? Have you tried Firefox?

Answer (score 2):

If the page has stopped responding this might not be possible, but you could try opening Chrome's developer tools (View->Developer->Developer Tools from the menubar, or right-clicking and choosing Inspect Element from the context menu) and attempting to locate the text you entered. For example if you are entering it in a `<textarea>`, then if you select the text area in the element tab, then the text you've entered should be available under the "value" property on the right-hand side of the window.

[image: Chrome Developer Tools Example]

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't been able to open Developer Tools either... :(

Comment: I don't think there is anyway for you to recover that text then. Is this something that happens repeatedly or is it just a once off issue you're dealing with just now?

Comment: It has happened before, but previously I was able to open the Developer Tools.

Comment: It might be worth investigating the hanging then. Have you tried a different browser or different machine? Do you still get the page hangs?

Comment: I know it's a problem with infinite loops in the page's JS.  However, my current issue is getting the code out of it once it's hung.  In future, I'll use a backup script.